# How to read Android IP Address status in Phone Info?

Tags: android, ip-address

In the Android Phone's Phone Status there are IP Address field in which from what I understand is shows the IP address assigned to the phone.

So, here's the question: my IT team said that they already set Wifi AP with IPv6 setup, but this is what it shows in my Phone Status:

> IP Address
>
> fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
>
> 2001::yyyy:yyyy:1234:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy
>
> 2001::zzzz:zzzz:1234:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz:zzzz
>
> 192.0.04

How to read which IP Protocol that I have? IPv6 only or both IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: The bottom line is ipv4. The rest could be ipv6

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but, which IP that my phone use on the connection? Is it v4 or v6?

Comment: It could be any one of them. It's up to your DHCP server to assign out addresses

Comment: @cricket_007 The thing is that I have feature that suppose to be tested using IPv6 only, so using above configuration it's prone that the result will not valid, roght? because we don't know which protocol were used for the connection?

Comment: I think you'd have to disable ipv4 on the DHCP server, then. I'm not aware of any Android setting to disable that